# How to get tag parameter value with XQuery

Tags: qt, xquery

For example i have this xml. I need to get value of parameter `val` of tag `foo` with `id="two"`

```
<top>
    <sub id="one">
        <foo id="two" val="bar" />
        sometext
    </sub>
</top>
```

Whis this query (using Qt QXmlQuery):

```
doc('test.xml')/top/sub[@id='one']/foo[@id='two']/<p>{@val}</p>
```

I receive `<p val="bar"/>`, **but I need only text "bar" without any tags**.
I tried to remove `<p>` and `</p>` and receive `syntax error, unexpected {`

**How can i get parameter value without any tags?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to serialize just an attribute you will get an error.  You may be better off just retrieving the value of the attribute:

```
doc('test.xml')/top/sub[@id='one']/foo[@id='two']/@val/data(.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry a bit late in the day...
try

```
data(doc('/db/test/test.xml')/top/sub[@id='one']/foo[@id='two']/@val)
```

which returns just the text value of the attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
doc('test.xml')/top/sub[@id='one']/foo[@id='two']/@val
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! But it not works with QXmlQuery. Internal serializer of QXmlQuery can process only valid XML (with tags, etc.) But @val returns only plain text (Actually what i need) and serializer can't process it.

For tag content (`sometext` in example) i use `text()`:
`doc('test.xml')/top/sub[@id='one']/foo[@id='two']/text()`
 to receive plain text, but for tag parameters it doesn't work. :(